# No power steering and coolant explosion

Tags: troubleshooting, coolant, subaru, power-steering

2008 Subaru WRX (Turbo)
I was pulling in to my parking spot and lost power steering looked at gauges and coolant temp was hot then white smoke/vapour from under the hood.  Turn car off, pop hood and coolant sprayed all over engine bay but mainly seems around the reservoir.

What should my steps be to diagnose and fix this?

Check power steering fluid level?
Check all rad hoses and such?
Put more coolant in and run the car to try and find the leak?

Comment: Is it possible the belt driving the power steering pump broke, and damaged a coolant hose when it failed?

Answer (score 1):

Well well well I found the culprit!!! On the 2008 WRX the radiator upper and lower is plastic and the top hose mount point was broken.  New radiator on its way.  Was a pretty easy find once I turned the car on and started jiggling hoses!